# Table cardinality information in Firebird

Tags: metadata, firebird

I am new to Firebird and I am messing around in it's meta data to get some information about the table structure and etc.

My problem is that I can't seem to find some information about estimated table cardinality. Is there a way to get this information from Firebird?

**Edit:**

By cardinality i mean the number of rows in a table :) and for my use the `select count(*)` is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aproximative method, using the selectivity of primary key like this:

```
SELECT
    R.RDB$RELATION_NAME TABLENAME,
    (
    CASE
      WHEN I.RDB$STATISTICS = 0 THEN 0
      ELSE 1 / I.RDB$STATISTICS
    END) AS COUNTRECORDS8
FROM RDB$RELATIONS R
  JOIN RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS C ON (R.RDB$RELATION_NAME = C.RDB$RELATION_NAME AND C.RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY')
  JOIN RDB$INDICES I ON (I.RDB$RELATION_NAME = C.RDB$RELATION_NAME AND I.RDB$INDEX_NAME = C.RDB$INDEX_NAME)
```

Comment: does this require that all tables have a primary key?, i can not assume that all tables have a primary key or an index at all!

Comment: Select Cont(*) is slow. If you need speed you can make a table with 2 fields "TableName" and "RecordCount" and with trigger for every table can maintain the number of records.

Comment: unfortunately I can't alter the table either :) , I'm only allowed to read, and in most cases the database i access have been in production for some while!

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of rows in a table you use the `COUNT()` function as in any other SQL DB, ie

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table;
```

Comment: unfortunately is the select count to slow

Comment: There is no other way, FB doesn't keep the count in some sys table or some similar... you could use triggers to maintain the "running count" in some other table but thats not relaiable and you should use it only if you need approximate count, not exact count of records.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a query:

```
select count(distinct field_name)/(count(field_name) + 0.0000) from table_name
```

The closer result to 1 the higher cardinality of a specified column.

Comment: @Sorry for mixing expressions a bit - by cardinality i mean the number of rows in a table :)

Comment: -> and a select count(*) is considered to slow for my purpose :)

Comment: @Harriv, I use the count as a part of meta data information about database' and the data is extracted often and on very different types of databases